# installing software without internet

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, usb

I need help installing a mt7601 wireless driver for linux. i have the files on usb but do not know how to install it in ubuntu.

Comment: What files do you have on USB? Dpkg archive (`.deb`), source archive (`.tar`,`.tgz`, ...), Windows driver?

Comment: Read readme file in the package..let us know if it is tar.gz or deb or rpm or what